# Space character issue with page to page form handling with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to pass the 'name' text field input to blank2.php.  I can send the data across
but anything after I type the space bar all the other input after it is omitted.  What am I missing?

**blank.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<title>First Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form action="http://www.example.com/blank2.php" method="post">
               <label for="name"></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name">
            <div>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send">            
            </div>
<div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the **second page:**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Second Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "http://example.com/blank3.php" method="post">
                <label for="name"></label>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" value=<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>>
        <br>
             <div>
            <input type="button" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send Message">            
            </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd really appreciate if if anyone can assist me.

Comment: One thing I note missing is that your name `value` should be wrapped in quotes in the second page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put quotes around the value.

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" id="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>">
```